# How to change the value of the Button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one more button on the page called Edit when I click on Edit button I need to Change the Add Button value to SAVE...using jquery..

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#edit_btn_id').click(function(){
    $('#badd').val('SAVE');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value of any input (including a button), like this:

```
​$("#badd").val("Save");​​​​​​
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/AFZ93/), or just plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("badd").value = "Save";
```